# How to display Kanji in non-X terminal?

Tags: command-line, xorg, unicode

I have Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop installed, but disabled the start of X, because I do > 99 % of my work in a terminal. However, I have found out that the "Linux" terminal is unable to display Kanji. I have tried installing `ttf-takao` and `ttf-takao-mincho`, but my terminal won't display them.

**Note**: Interestingly, when starting xterm on X, it doesn't show them either, even though my locale is set to "de_AT.UTF-8".

- Is there any way to display them in my terminal?

---

**For clarification**: The question was how to display them in a non-X terminal, not xterm. The note was just to give additional info

Comment: FYI - the "non-X terminal" is called a console.

Comment: I know, but some users see "Console" and "Terminal" as the same. I just wanted to make things 100 % clear